# Twitters Typeahead - on rendered, loop each result

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I am working with Twitters Typeahead.js, and I've been stuck with a problem, asking around everywhere, but nobody seem to know how to fix it.

I simply want to loop each of the results when Twitter Typeahead.js has been rendered, like for instance:

$('span.tt-suggestions img').each(function() { // code here } );

Does anybody know a workaround, or is this simply impossible? I have been trying every simple possibility.

See examples of typehead here: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Bind an event handler to `typeahead:opened`, and in it do what you suggested:

`$('.tt-suggestion').each(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I did't have so much knowledge about `Twitters Typeahead`.

But in your example you bind jquery `.each` function with `img` element, but there is no img exist.

So I think you should bind `.each` loop with inner class `.tt-suggestion` or inner `<p>` element.

Try this:

```
$('.tt-suggestion').each(function(){ // your code});
```

or

```
$('.tt-suggestions .tt-suggestion').each(function(){ // your code});
```

or

```
$('span.tt-suggestions .tt-suggestion').each(function(){ // your code});
```

I hope it will help you...!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved!

Solution:

```
        var topbarTypeahead = $('#myInput').typeahead();
        topbarTypeahead.data('ttView').dropdownView.on('suggestionsRendered', function() {
            // suggestions has now been rendered.
            // do whatever you want here.
        });
```